# Java / Eclipse: Removing multiple warnings for 'Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings'

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, warnings

I'm working on a legacy Java App that has about 6k warnings that I am trying to clean up. One of them is simply "Unnecessary @Suppresswarnings('XXXX')". Eclipse has a quick fix for this, but there are several hundred in the codebase, and even more instances where it is actually used.

I would like to be able to apply the "Quick Fix" (remove unused tokens), on all these warnings at once, but can't seem to find a way to make that happen. Since there are many (more) instances of this annotation being used that aren't generating warnings, a brute-force strip of the annotations would just create more warnings.

Is there a way to do this in eclipse (or maybe a third-party tool), or am I just out of luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to do this outside of Eclipse. Maybe a quick shell script with sed / awk would be enough? If you have complicated rules, you could always write another Java program to strip things out.

Comment: I mentioned in the original question that there is a lot of code using the annotations correctly, and going that route actually generates _more_ issues.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way you could tell during parsing if you wanted to keep the annotation or not. If the ratio of bad to good is high enough, maybe it's faster to remove them all and add the necessary ones back in rather than the other way around?

Comment: Thats basically what I did, so you get the point. I wasn't thinking about doing an annotation processor on the code, but just going search/replace and a brute force fix was probably faster. Now if I just had a way to fix all the freaking generics errors.

Answer (score 4):

I would love to be wrong but I think you're out of luck. I know of no way to apply a quick fix to multiple warnings at once.